# Ubuntu 18.04 Suspend loop

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, laptop

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 on my razer laptop (2017 14") and everything was working fine (for the most part) until I ran into an issue that seems to trigger once I suspend my laptop (by closing the lid).

Basically it suspends just fine, however once I open the lid it runs for a small period of time (seconds) before locking and suspending the system again (even while typing or working with the system).

Looking at the syslogs I see the following groups of messages appear.

````
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd-sleep[7640]: System resumed.
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer kernel: [  693.623692] PM: suspend exit
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Oct  6 00:26:26 mkw-ubuntu-razer systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.```
````

The only way to stop this process is by completely rebooting the system. I saw I could disable suspend on lid closed, but I like that functionality and would love to have it work on this machine (works great on my Precision 5520).

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to learn about Power Management.

Answer (score 2):

So this is actually a known issue with the Razer and is easily resolved with a GRUB change.  The official link for the documentation is here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade#Suspend

Comment: Worked also on Toshiba Satellite Pro T130

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is not to late but i have found a solution. I have the same Razer Blade 14 (2017 with the GTX 1060 7700HQ 512GB 1080P).

What fix it for me was during installation i customized my partitions.

What i did:

1. main partition: / ext4 xxx GB
2. boot partition: /boot/efi fat32 500MB
3. swap partition: linux-swap xx GB (your RAM GB + 2 EXTRA GB)

After you did this you have to apply changes and install.

After that i went to folder /boot/efi/loader/entries/*.conf file. Remember this can vary, i use Pop_Os 18.04 so mine is Pop_Os-current.conf.

options root=UUID=238db2d4-0050-4bd4-b283-65e192dda494 ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash button.lid_init_state=open

Here behind "options" on the end of this line i added button.lid_init_state=open

Aswell as in /etc/default/grub. This seemed to work for my Razer Blade 14 from 2017! (RZ09-0195E72)

Comment: I have to add that everytime you update or upgrade your system, the conf file could be overwritten. So you have to keep track with this.. atleast the issue is in the conf file when you have a FAT32 EFI boot option