# Libreoffice preventing the computer from resuming from suspend Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, libreoffice

I started a thread about this a few months ago because I was thinking that a problem I've been having with resuming my computer from suspend mode was as a result of my power saving settings. However now I know for sure that this is not the case, as I thought that I had "fixed" the problem a while back, and thought everything was working fine until I had the same issue happen again twice this past week, both times when libreoffice was open. If I do not have libreoffice open, the computer goes into sleep mode and resumes from it like normal. How could Libreoffice cause such a massive problem as this?

Now that I think about it, every single time the computer screen remains blank instead of resuming from suspend mode I've been running libreoffice. I also don't use the program every day, explaining why it has been an intermittent issue.

What should I do about this? I can't just not use libreoffice, I'm a college student. I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and have been updating regularly every week or so.

EDIT/Update: I'm starting this thread again because, although I thought I had solved the problem, this week I've had the exact same issues occur, and only when libreoffice was open.

Comment: So this is the actually the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054626/507051)? Did you try other posts like https://askubuntu.com/q/1034185/507051, https://askubuntu.com/q/1029405/507051, https://askubuntu.com/q/1035208/507051, https://askubuntu.com/q/1077436/507051 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1081361/507051? What did you find out, what errors did you encounter?

Comment: Your comment is not helpful. All of those questions you've linked me to are non-sequitors and I've never had the black screen on resume from suspend unless I had Libre Office open. Ever. I've reported the bug with FULL ERROR CODE STACK to bugzilla too and they are trying to blame it on me as well.

Comment: So just so it's super duper clear: No, it's not the same problem at all and I have literal evidence to prove it.